# Missing concrete implementation of StatelessWidget

Tags: flutter

This page is my PhotoPreviewScreen where I send the photo that comes from the camera screen to the home page after clicking the button in the code below.

I am getting some interesting errors, that I have not seen before with very little in the docs, which are in the screenshot.
Has anyone seen these before? How can I rectify?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';

class PhotoPreviewScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  Function setData;
  PhotoPreviewScreen({Key key, this.setData}) : super(key: key);
}

class _PhotoPreviewScreenState extends State<PhotoPreviewScreen> {
  final String imagePath;
  var image;

  Future _openGallery() async {}


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(
            context), // Go back to the camera to take the picture again
        child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Photo Preview')),
      body: Column(children: [
        Expanded(child: Image.file(File(imagePath))),
        const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
        OutlineButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _openGallery();
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Text('Okay'),
          borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Color(
                  0xff33333D)), 
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

errors

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
class PhotoPreviewScreen extends StatefulWidget {Function setData;   PhotoPreviewScreen({Key key, this.setData}) : super(key: key); }
```

I guess it should be "StatefulWidget" instead of "StatelesWidget".

Comment: Still get the first and third error, but now for StatefulWidget.createState

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code snippets:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';

class PhotoPreviewScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  Function setData;
  PhotoPreviewScreen({Key key, this.setData}) : super(key: key);

_PhotoPreviewScreenState createState() => _PhotoPreviewScreenState();
}

class _PhotoPreviewScreenState extends State<PhotoPreviewScreen> {
  final String imagePath = ' ';
  var image;

  Future _openGallery() async {}


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(
            context), // Go back to the camera to take the picture again
        child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Photo Preview')),
      body: Column(children: [
        Expanded(child: Image.file(File(imagePath))),
        const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
        OutlineButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _openGallery();
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Text('Okay'),
          borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Color(
                  0xff33333D)), 
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```